# What does Switch do?

Tags: reactjs, react-router-v4

I have the following code:

```js
import {Route, Switch} from 'react-router-dom';

<Route exact path="/" component={Landing} />
<div className="container">
  <Route path="/register" render={() => (
    <Register {...this.props} />
  )}/>
  <Route path="/login" render={() => (
    <Login {...this.props}/>
  )}/>
  <Switch>
    <PrivateRoute path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard}/>
  </Switch>
  <Switch>
    <PrivateRoute path="/create-profile" component={CreateProfile}/>
  </Switch>
```

After the user logs in (using `/login`), he's been redirected to `/dashboard`.
However, if I remove the `<Switch>` from the `/dashboard`, the user is still being redirected to `/dashboard` but that `Dashboard` component doesn't get rendered.

So how exactly does that `<Switch>` work?

Comment: The `Switch` component makes sure that the first `Route` inside it that match gets rendered, and stops there. Maybe you have another `Switch` and `Route` further up your application that matches `/dashboard`?

Comment: @Tholle i edited my post with the complete list of Routes and Switches.

Comment: Have a look in the [official switch docs](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/core/api/Switch)

Comment: I still don't understand - if i don't use `Switch`, would it render a different component when i go to `/dashboard`?

Comment: the code that you provided in the question is the complete render function? or are you missing some parts...

Comment: Nope, that's everything.

Answer (score -1):

Removing the Switch inclusively renders the Login and Dashboard component as direct children. After login, you are redirected to the '/dashboard' url but the Dashboard does not get re-rendered because both Routes match this path.

The Switch component exclusively renders the first child path that matches the current url.